# How to add the time.sleep() after every 100 iterations?

Tags: python, for-loop, time

For example, I have the next list:

```
`l = ['a1', 'c4', 'p8', ... , '9i']`
```

The list contains 1000 values -> `print(len(l)) = 1000`

My next action, it is iteration the `list`

```
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

I need to add `time.sleep(10)` to this process after every 100 iterations, **but once `time.sleep(60)` should be after the first iteration (at the beginning)**. How I can to do this? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't name your list `list` because it will shadow the keyword.  The rest you can do with the modulo operator `%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to both iterate on the value and it's position

- `i==0` will sleep `60`
- `i%100==0` (100, 200, 300, ...) will sleep `10`

```
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    print(value)
    if i == 0:
        time.sleep(60)
    elif i % 100 == 0:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i, item in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    if i == 1:
        time.sleep(60)
    elif i % 100:
        time.sleep(10)
    print(item)
```

Comment: No need for an `if`. Move the first sleep outside the loop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, he needs it to sleep for 60 seconds after first iteration.

Comment: That's not what your code is doing tho

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
import time

first_iteration = True

for x in list:
  print(x)
  if first_iteration:
    time.sleep(60)
  elif x % 100 == 0:
    time.sleep(10)
  first_iteration = False
```